# character navigation in unity3d for isometric games

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, isometric

I am a beginner in unity I wish to learn pathfinding tutorials on isometric tiles and rotating 2d sprites implemented by the pathfinding system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playlist about programming A* pathfinding in Unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cq5Umv3pMC9SPnKjfp9eGW

As for the sprite rotation, you could use a sprite sheet that changes depending on the direction your characters move.